# Iterating through properties of a object

Tags: .net, powershell, properties

I have the following objects:

```
$restrictedPrograms = @(
    @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Visual Studio Test"};
    @{Guid = "102C29B2-4320-4774-8003-6912F0AC19"};
    @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us"};
    @{Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD98"};
    @{DisplayName = "SourceTre"; Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD981"}
)
```

The restricted items can have only one property(DisplayName or Guid) or both.

```
$installedPrograms = @(
        @{DisplayName = "SourceTree"; Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD981"};
        @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0"; Guid = "FEB375AB-6EEC-3929-8FAF-188ED81DD8B5"}
    )
```

I want to iterate through each of the installedPrograms and compare those properties in restrictedPrograms. I know how to do this by hardcoding the property names(DisplayName and Guid):

```
foreach($installedProgram in $installedPrograms)
    {
        foreach($restrictedProgram in $restrictedPrograms)
        {
            if($restrictedProgram.DisplayName -and $restrictedProgram.Guid)
            {
                if(($installedProgram.DisplayName -eq $restrictedProgram.DisplayName) -and ($installedProgram.Guid -eq $restrictedProgram.Guid))
                {
                    return $false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($restrictedProgram.DisplayName)
                {
                    if($installedProgram.DisplayName -eq $restrictedProgram.DisplayName)
                    {
                        return $false;
                    }
                }

                if($restrictedProgram.Guid)
                {
                    if($installedProgram.Guid -eq $restrictedProgram.Guid)
                    {
                        return $false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But how can I do this by iterating through the properties of restrictedProgram item, instead of hardcoding it:

```
foreach($installedProgram in $installedPrograms)
    {
        foreach($restrictedProgram in $restrictedPrograms)
        {
            // Foreach property in $restrictedProgram, compare it with the corresponding property in $installedProgram ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: So to clarify if the displayname _or_ the guid  of an entry in `$installedPrograms` matches that of an entry in the restricted list that is a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I am perfectly clear what you are doing with the results after the fact but from the looks of it you are looking to see if any the properties in `$installedPrograms` are present in the same property values of `$restrictedPrograms`. I made PowerShell object of your hashtables as that opened up many avenues. Mostly I wanted to be able to use `Compare-Object` but since I was not sure of you expected results I skipped it over.

```
$installedPrograms = @(
        @{DisplayName = "SourceTree"; Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD981"};
        @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0"; Guid = "FEB375AB-6EEC-3929-8FAF-188ED81DD8B5"}
) | ForEach-Object{New-Object PSObject -Property $_}

$restrictedPrograms = @(
    @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Visual Studio Test"};
    @{Guid = "102C29B2-4320-4774-8003-6912F0AC19"};
    @{DisplayName = "Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us"};
    @{Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD98"};
    @{DisplayName = "SourceTree"; Guid = "B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD981"}
) | ForEach-Object{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
        Guid = $_.Guid
    }
}


$installedPrograms | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -in $restrictedPrograms.DisplayName -or $_.Guid -in $restrictedPrograms.Guid}
```

The last line is all that matters. From the looks of it you have at least PowerShell 3.0 so this should work just fine for you. For each `$installedPrograms` we check if it has a matching display name or guid. If a match is found it is passed through the pipe. So my interpreted end result here is a list of Restricted Programs that are installed on the computer.

```
DisplayName Guid                                
----------- ----                                
SourceTree  B24E0C46-B627-4781-975E-620ED53CD981
```

You had mentioned though you wanted this to be more dynamic. So with that in mind I changed the logic to allow for dynamic properties. We make the comparisons without previously knowing what the properties are. For sake of simplicity I am not going to remake the PowerShell objects in the same vien as I am not sure if your are interested in this approach.

```
$matchedPrograms = @()
$props = ($installedPrograms | Select-Object -First 1).PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach($singleProgram in $installedPrograms){
    ForEach($singleProperty in $props){
        # Check to see $singleProperty of $singleProgam is in $restrictedPrograms
        If($singleProgram.$singleProperty -in $restrictedPrograms.$singleProperty){$matchedPrograms += $singleProgram}
    }
}

$matchedPrograms | Select-Object -Unique
```

Since was are looking for matching individually it is possible that there will be double of programs and `-Unique` will take care of that.

Comment: @Romonov if this helped I would love to know which part you were actually interested in .

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped:

```
foreach($installedProgram in $installedPrograms)
    {
        foreach($restrictedProgram in $restrictedPrograms)
        {
            $count = 0
            foreach($key in $restrictedProgram.Keys)
            {
                if($installedProgram.$key -eq $restrictedProgram.$key)
                {
                    $count++
                }
            }

            if($count -eq $restrictedProgram.Keys.Count)
            {
                Write-Host "Found the restricted program " $restrictedProgram.Values " installed"
                return $false;
            }
        }
    }
```